# What can I claim when there is a loss in the business?

Tags: united-states, small-business, limited-liability-company

I purchased 49% shares of a LLC business(Paid $150,000) and the business is claiming a loss of $ 130,000 for the 2014 year. I worked full time at the business but did not take a paycheck at all. Can my spouse claim any of the business loss if we file jointly? 
Will it be a tax credit or a deduction?

Comment: Tax questions require that you specify your country.

Comment: This question was flagged 'unclear' as it had no country. Is the question worth keeping if we treat it as US? If not, the close votes will take care of it.

Comment: Nitpick: Is this really _personal_ finance?

Comment: @keshlam I think the core of the question is about the spouse's *personal* income tax return, so yes.